# Lutris doesn't see Vulkan

Tags: flatpak, vulkan

I've just installed Lutris through flathub and I'd like to run a DXVK game but Lutris can't see Vulkan for some reason. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Hello @Qushy. Please provide more information (with examples if possible) about problems you're experiencing and what have you tried so far to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this issue, did you get anywhere with this?

Vulkan drivers are installed and working on the Lutris version installed via apt but when I use the Flatpak version I get the following error:

[image: Image showing vulkan error]

This is also true of wine, I got a similar message when installing a new game.

Comment: I actually think I was missing a runtime. If you go to the thread at the Lutris Forums I've actually posted the command to install the runtime there by it may be outdated by now.